# Is it possible to use configmap with hostPath in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Instead of using direct configuration for volume host path, like

```
 volumes:
    - name: mongo-24
      hostPath:
        path: /my/path/to/file/or/directory
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

I want to put this into configmap, so I have tried this one:

```
  volumes:
    - name: myVolume
      hostPath:
        path: 
          valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: common-config
            key: MY_VOLUME_PATH
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

but this was not successful, because:

> error validating data: expected type string, for field
>   spec.template.spec.volumes[0].hostPath.path, got map

Is it possible to use hostPath / path with config map?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, no. The question is, why do you need it / what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I have different environments with different configurations, and I want to put common parts in deployment definition, and have only different parts is configmap

Comment: I would suggest using higher level solution that allows for templating of resources created in kube like [Helm](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm), that way you can use helm values to modify config per env.